# .h file not found when import header file from existing framework

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have a my.m under {projectRoot}/Libraries/myLib/myLib/Sources/
In my.m:

```
#import <X/X.h>
```

It's saying X/X.h file not found.
Actually, I can locate X.h under {projectRoot}/Frameworks/myFW.framework/Headers/

What should I set up for xcode to be able to search for X.h in my.m?

Comment: c++, objective-c, c, xcode - what is it?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. It's objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. click your project menu and choose build settings
   2.input "header search paths"
   3.input your ".h" file's project path,"$(inherited)" is your project root path.

[image]